# Port boundaries for California

Tags: data, united-states

I'm interested in finding GIS data for ports in California. I have a point layer but I'm hoping to find polygons for each port. Surprisingly this is proving to be more difficult than first expected.

Comment: Have a look at this page: http://www.dot.ca.gov/hq/tsip/gis/datalibrary/

Comment: I haven't time to check but have you had a look at OpenStreetMap? You may be able to download outline from there. Otherwise has a look at county GIS resources such as lacountry.gov  http://egis3.lacounty.gov/dataportal/interactive-map/

Comment: Thanks anja I've checked out Caltrans (good source) but unfortunately only point layer for ports as far as I can see. spk578 haven't come across your link will check it out. Appreciate the replys :-)